# jQuery: Custom autocomplete list doesn't redraw itself on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I've written a basic autocomplete function that takes an array of data and displays it underneath a search bar. When a user inputs a single character, everything works fine - the list displays matches and clicking on an item in the list dismisses the list and adds the clicked item to the search bar. However, if someone wanted to change/refine their search value with more than one character, I noticed something happening:

**1. The function would draw additional copies (with new values) of the `<ul>` result list instead of redrawing the original list.**

**2. Clicking on a target `<li>` in the list doesn't dismiss the list.**

The function is called whenever a `keyup` is detected. `filterAutocomplete` takes the input of the appropriate search bar and gets an array of items to pass to my main function, `doAutocomplete`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#projectIDFrom").on('keyup', (function(){
             var val = $(this).val().trim();
             val = val.replace(/\s+/g, '');
             var id = $("#projectIDFrom").attr('id');
             filterAutoComplete(val, id);
             }

        ));      
})
```

Below is the main function.

```
    function doAutocomplete(list, storeInput){
     var query = $("#"+storeInput).val()
     var drew = false;
     //assign unique ID to results (handles multiple search bars on a page)
     var resID = storeInput+ "Res";

        //Build the box only if there's a value greater than 0
        //in the target search bar
        if($("#"+storeInput).val().length > 0){

                //Case insensitive search for our array
                var results = $.grep(list, function(item){
                    return item.search(RegExp(query, "i")) != -1;
                });

            //First search (no pre-existing list)
            if(drew == false){
                //Create list for results
                $("#"+storeInput).after("<ul class='autoResult' id='"+ resID +"'></ul>");

                //Prevent redrawing/binding of list
                drew = true;

                //Bind click event to list elements in results
                $("#"+resID).on("click", "li", function(){
                    $("#"+storeInput).val($(this).text());
                    $("#"+resID).remove();
                 });
            }
            //remove if the value in search bar changes
            //redraw occurs on next keypress
            else if (drew == true){
                $("#"+resID).remove();
            }

            //Add matching results to the list
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                $("#"+resID).append("<li>" + results[i] + "</li>");
            }
        }
        //Handle backspace/delete so results don't remain
        else if($("#"+storeInput).val().length < 1){
            $("#"+resID).remove();
        }
}
```

***How can I avoid drawing multiple copies of the results list, and get the function to simply draw/redraw a single list with new results?***

[Link to JSFiddle that reproduces the issues I outlined above.](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/m6sm3u24/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the remove code before you start to build the box. Following is the code. see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6sm3u24/5/)

```
function doAutocomplete(list, storeInput) {
        var query = $("#" + storeInput).val()
        var resID = storeInput + "Res"; //projectIDFromRes
        $("#" + resID).remove();
        //Build the box only if it there's actually a value greater than 0 in the target search bar
        if ($("#" + storeInput).val().length > 0) {

            //Case insensitive search for our  array
            var results = $.grep(list, function (item) {
                return item.search(RegExp(query, "i")) != -1;
            });
            //First search

            //Create list for results
            $("#" + storeInput).after("<ul class='autoResult' id='" + resID + "'></ul>");

            //Prevent redrawing/binding of list


            //Bind click event to list elements in results
            $("#" + resID).on("click", "li", function () {
                $("#" + storeInput).val($(this).text());
                $("#" + resID).remove();
            });

            //Add results to the list
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $("#" + resID).append("<li>" + results[i] + "</li>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,
Yeou

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense! Everything seems to be working as expected. [Check out the updated JSFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/m6sm3u24/7/)